# Can I get the project manager pieced added using sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Tags: ms-project

Can I get the project manager pieced added using sharepoint 2010 or 2013

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Can you rephrase and add some detail?

Comment: Hello, Yes  I am would like to work with Project Manager adding a pieced into the sharepoint? I am not using project server but I am using sharepoint directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Sync-with-a-SharePoint-tasks-list-fb956d2c-723d-4d5a-b7e5-710ef82aa27a) is how to sync content between MS Project and SharePoint (recent versions of both since you didn't specify

(From MS Office Support site above)

1. In Project, click  File > Save.
2. In the Sync with list, select Existing SharePoint Site.
3. In the Site Address box, type the address of the SharePoint tasks list that  you want to import.
4. Click Verify Site.
5. In the Tasks List box, type or select a name for the tasks list that you want to sync with your project.